# How to add times together with Momentjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, momentjs

I have an application that logs when a device is turned on and turned off. It logs the details in a mysql db. I want to calculate for how long the device has been on. I use jquery/ajax to get two sets of data: ON and OFF, in two arrays.

The DB structure:

```
  device id             logtime           status
---------------------------------------------------
17x1p14e6662  April 12th 2017, 1:05:52 pm   ON
17x1p14e6662  April 12th 2017, 1:06:34 pm   OFF
 .... etc
```

I then loop through them to calculate the time difference. This works fine. How can I then add all the resulting time outputs into a single time?

this is part of the jquery/ajax:

the response from my php backend is:

```
{"result":{"trueresults":[["April 12th 2017, 1:05:52 pm"],["April 12th 2017, 1:05:54 pm"],["April 12th 2017, 1:06:54 pm"],["April 12th 2017, 4:54:10 pm"]],"falseresults":[["April 12th 2017, 1:05:53 pm"],["April 12th 2017, 1:05:55 pm"],["April 12th 2017, 1:07:02 pm"],["April 12th 2017, 4:56:18 pm"]]},"errors":false}
```

the actual jQuery code:

```
    .success(function(response) {
        if(!response.errors && response.result) {        

            var trueresultgroup = response.result.trueresults;
            var falseresultgroup = response.result.falseresults;

                for (i = 0; i < trueresultgroup.length; i++) {                  
                    var on = (trueresultgroup[i]).toString();
                    var off = (falseresultgroup[i]).toString();
                    var ms = moment(off,"MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a").diff(moment(on,"MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"));
                    var d = moment.duration(ms);
                    var s = d.format("hh [hours] :mm [minutes] :ss [seconds]");
                    $("#divtimes").append('<p>'+s+'</p>');


                }

        } else {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

So the output in my html looks like this:

```
<div id="divtimes" class="m-b-30"><p>01 seconds</p><p>01 seconds</p><p>08 seconds</p><p>02 minutes :08 seconds</p></div>
```

My desired output should be the sum of all of this:

```
02 minutes :18 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply calculate the sum of all duration inside the loop and print the result outside the loop.

Start with a duration of 0 ms (`moment.duration(0)`), then add the calculated diffs using [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/add/). Print the result outside of the loop.

Your code could be like the following:

```
// Create a duration of 0 ms
var tot = moment.duration(0);
for (i = 0; i < trueresultgroup.length; i++) {                  
  var on = (trueresultgroup[i]).toString();
  var off = (falseresultgroup[i]).toString();
  var ms = moment(off,"MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a").diff(moment(on,"MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"));
  tot.add(ms, 'ms');
}
var s = tot.format("hh [hours] :mm [minutes] :ss [seconds]");
$("#divtimes").append('<p>'+s+'</p>');
```

Comment: Aha! Perfect. Thank you so much Vincenzo, I didn't think of adding a `(moment.duration(0))`, it makes sense now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Since you are already setting durations, you can use the add duration to combine the times like so:

```
var duration = moment.duration({'days' : 1});
moment([2012, 0, 31]).add(duration); // February 1
```

Comment: how can I do it in a loop like I have?

Comment: Thanks for your help! It got me a step closer to what I wanted. I appreciate it.